My Schengen visa application for France was rejected. What can I do next?
I am a 22-year-old student who graduated two years ago. Currently, I'm taking a break and plan to start my master's next year.
My trip was sponsored by my brother, who has a good financial standing.
I didn't provide a detailed daily itinerary, but I did submit a dummy flight ticket and hotel reservation.
My application was rejected. Should I apply again in France or try a different embassy, or should I not apply at all since I'm unemployed?

I think you can forget about a Schengen visa until you have a stable situation.

What reason(s) was given for the refusal? See eg

"dummy flight ticket and hotel reservation". Massive red flag right there. Would make the officials think you're hiding plans to stay in the EU and to underground, working illegally.

@jwenting false some countries might not need confirmed tickets a reservation or reserved ticket works and it’s sometimes known as dummy ticket

The visa officials must decide if you appear similar to a genuine tourist, or similar to an illegal immigrant.

The money is one big factor. It must come from a documented source, and it must appear reasonable to be spent on tourism. It is reasonable for one brother to give a gift to another brother. It may or may not  be reasonable to give that much, and it may or may not be reasonable for the recipient of the gift to spend it on tourism.
Ask yourself how many months you could live in your country with that money. It looks bad if you spend too much, compared to your lifestyle.

But your ties to the homeland are also a big factor. Do you appear to have good reasons to return? Good reasons would include a stable, well-paid job, or a house, or family who do not travel with you.
It would appear that you do not qualify in this regard.


So without knowing the details of your case, it seems to be a bad idea to reapply until your situation changes.

It's worth pointing out explicitly that two refusals in a row are much, much worse than one refusal. That's what makes it a bad idea to apply again unless you're sure your application is perfectly watertight this time (and that might involve waiting for a few years).

This answer doesn’t really offer and advice

@SaranshSharma, last sentence: do not reapply until there is a solid job or another significant change of circumstances.

So by your logic a student should not apply until they have a job ? That’s such baseless

@SaranshSharma, the OP is currently unemplyed, between graduation (bachelor?) and master. Not a student. And it depends on the rest of the circumstances, which I mentioned. Having been rejected once, another application should wait for a change.

Your options are limited, strongly suggest not to apply one more fresh application chances are that it will be rejected. Another option is applying for an appeal to French embassy as you mentioned that you didn’t provide a detailed itinerary. Now you can put together an appeal which includes your detailed itinerary and your cause why you are not a flight risk !
Submitting a dummy ticket if they are reserved is not a problem even embassies suggest not to book actual / confirmed flights or reservations before visa approval !

A dummy ticket, as pointed out by @jwenting in comments, is by itself a huge red flag. And because consulates and government visa agencies are well-versed in this area, they know about dummy tickets. Downvoted.

No it’s a not a huge red flag embassies don’t need a confirmed tickets they need to see a reservation and in my opinion here dummy tickets are reserved tickets. Except some countries that may need to see actual paid and confirmed tickets
